# jQuery Regex to allow only a currency symbol and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery's validation plugin to validate form text fields.
I'm trying to validate a price field by only allowing currency symbols, letters and numbers but no other special characters.

I have tried this but it's allowing other special characters such as ; " :

```
^[a-zA-Z 0-9 € £]+$
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Code in document.ready function:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("acceptPrice", function(value, element, param) {
            return value.match(new RegExp(param + "$"));
         });

    $("#editForm").validate({
          onkeyup: false,
    rules: {


        priceField: { acceptPrice: "^[a-zA-Z0-9€£]+$" },


        }
```

Comment: Well you don't need the spaces (use `^[a-zA-Z0-9€£]+$`), but even with the spaces that regex would not allow those other punctuation characters like semicolons. Can you show the code where you apply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regex pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9€£]+$`

Even your wrong pattern does not allow characters such as `;`, `"` or `:`. You must have some error in your code, not just in regex pattern.

***UPDATE [1]***

If you want to allow also space character, then use regex pattern `^[ a-zA-Z0-9€£]+$`

***UPDATE [2]***

If you want to allow also decimal numbers, you need to allow dot as well: `^[. a-zA-Z0-9€£]+$`

***UPDATE [3]***

JavaScript Form Validation

```
<form name="myForm" action="form.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

...with script:

```
function validateForm()
{
  // if error return false;
  // if okay  return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks but it still won't let me type "2 euro" for example, is it because the number is at the start?

Comment: @Dave - You have to then allow also spaces! See my updated answer. Show us your code that verify the input.

Comment: is there a way to prevent the form from submitting if there are any validation errors?

Comment: Yes, you're right about the space - I've deleted my incorrect comment. (I assumed when Dave said he wanted only "currency symbols, letters and numbers" that that was what he meant...)